# Why would Mail's message counts not match Gmail's?

Tags: mail.app, gmail, google-apps

I have Mail 4.5 on 10.6.7 and a Google apps account.

My total message counts for each folder in Mail don't match the counts I see in the GMail web UI.

I don't have any custom labels or folders. I've tried rebuilding the mailbox in Mail, syncing the account, and switching the message view to "threaded". No dice.

Inbox, Sent, and Trash have always been off and Mail always shows more.

- Inbox:  62(GM) / 78(Mail)
- Sent:   88(GM) / 117(Mail)
- Trash:  199(GM) / 262(Mail)

Comment: Do you use POP or IMAP to connect to Gmail from Mail.app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gmail counts all mail of a thread to 1 mail. Your version's Mail app not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought of that but, when I enable the threaded view of messages in Mail, the count still doesn't add up (still fewer). BTW, the message count doesn't change in the title bar -- you have to tally them manually.

Comment: Threading or not threading in Mail makes no difference to the count - you need to change the threading in Gmail to change its count if you can

Comment: You're right! For others searching for this... in GMail, go to the top right corner and click the gear icon. Choose "Mail Settings" from the drop down menu. The "General" settings tab will load. Find "Conversation View:". Select "Conversation view off" and click "Save Changes" at the bottom. You may have to synchronize the account in Mail.app or just restart Mail.app.